# Scale down image such that it fills a square of 100x100

Tags: resize, imagemagick, image-processing, batch, convert-command

I want to create thumbnails for all images of a folder. I also want the images to fit in a square of 100x100 pixels.

So after scaling the images down, while the smaller side needs to be 100 pixels, the larger side should be cropped so as to make it equal to 100.

With ImageMagick I have tried:

```
for i in $(ls *.jpg); do convert -scale 100 $i th-$i; done
```

It works but for an example image of 1000x800, the scaled down image has a size of 100x80 instead of 100x100.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
for i in $(ls *.jpg); do convert -resize 100x100^ -gravity center -crop 100x100+0+0 $i th-$i; done
```

You can find more examples of resizing and scaling [here](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/resize/), "
Resizing to Fill a Given Space" seems to be most relevant to your problem.

Comment: Thank you, but that didn't work. It just created some more images, but with their initial sizes.

Comment: Which version of ImageMagick are you using? Because [Resizing to Fill a Given Space](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/resize/#fill) also mentions this: 

"As of IM v6.3.8-3 a new resize flag '^' will let you do this directly as a single resize step. These examples represent an alternative method that can be used for users with older versions of ImageMagick."

Answer (score 0):

The following method may be helpful:

```
for i in *.jpg
do
convert "$i" -resize 100x100 -background white -compose Copy \
-gravity center -extent 100x100 "${i%.jpg}_thumb.jpg"
done
```

You should alter the background colour according to the background colour of your file manager...